# Transforming a categorical distribution up side down

Tags: distributions, categorical-data, smoothing

I have the following categorical distribution:

$$
original = (2, 7, 3, 5, 0, 1, 4, 6, 3, 8, 8)\\
\sum original = 47
$$

I want to transform it to its upside down distribution step by step, while keeping the total indifferent, and save the intermediate distributions after each step.
$$
upside\_down = (6.54, 1.54, 5.54, 3.54, 8.54, 7.54, 4.54, 2.54, 5.54, 0.54, 0.54)\\
\sum upside\_down = 46.94 \text{, which is approximately 47}
$$

To make it clear, I want to move from red original distribution to blue upside_down distribution via mean distribution in *n* number of steps. At the end of the process I will have *n+1* distributions saved (original + *n* new distributions), which I will use for some calculations. (I'm using a line chart for clarity, data are actually categorical)

[image]

At the moment, I am subtracting the *original* from 2 x *mean* distribution to find the *upside_down* distribution. Then I can divide the distance from value in *original* to the respective value in *upside_down* to *n* number of portions to get values of each distribution.

$$
i'th\ value\ of\ j'th\ distribution = original(i) -  (original(i) - upside\_down(i))\times \dfrac{j}{n}
$$

Is there a standard way to do this, other than what I am doing above?

Is there a proper term for what I call upside_down distribution?

Comment: Your transformation is more easily achieved as -original + 2* mean (two steps). That bit seems straightforward, although it would help readers to understand your motivation for doing this better. I'm afraid I do not understand the n-1 distributions in between. Are these partial differences between the two extremes? Or do you want to store the distribution after each arithmetic operation? Or is it saving the distribution after transforming each observation in turn (so it will be $transformed_1...transformed_i, original _{j+1}....original_n$?

Comment: My description on getting *upside_down* was wrong, thanks for pointing it out.
Sorry, all the 3 possibilities you ask above sound similar to me. I am trying to understand how a statistical test behaves when two compared distributions deviate from each other at different levels. That is why I need to find intermediate distributions, between the worst (*upside_down*) and the *original*.
I'm not a mathematician or a statistician so, I'd like to know if there is any standard way to generate the distributions and a vocabulary to communicate technical details. Thanks